# an exercice of sum in list

Tags: arrays, c, list, sum

hello I'm trying to solve an exercise about the sequence of numbers in a list with the greatest sum:
I need to write a (non-recursive) function that returns the largest sum of numbers in the list.
example:
in the list:[-1,4,-10,9,14,-4]
need to return 23 because 9+14=23 and its the maximum sum in this list.
i'm beeginer in C and don't know how using deboguer with list in C?
can you help me to undersand where are my problems?

```
int sum_lst(int lst[],int debut,int fin){
    int i=debut,sum=0;
    for (i;i<fin;i++){
        sum+=lst[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
int max_sum(int lst[],int n){
    int i=n;
    static int sum;
    int j=0;
    for (i;i>0;i--){
        for (j;j<n;j++){
            if (sum_lst(lst,j,i)>sum){
                sum= sum_lst(lst,i,j);
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Bonjour :), you should first find the two highest number and sum them. It's better if we don't give you the answer ( it is very easy)

Comment: 1> sort the list descending (maybe using library sort)
2> get the first two Items (or the last two if you sort descending)
3> voila

Comment: @DDS What should be the output for `[10, -20, -30, 40, -50]`?

Comment: Don't know how to use debugger? Then let's learn! [debugging - What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: 50, of course: sorted vector will be `[50, 40, -20, -30, -50]` but it depends on how you implement the comparing function to the sort. Remember: if standard library has a function for it, just use it.

Comment: Do the numbers have to be adjacent? (i.e. *subarrays*)

Comment: Does this help? [C / C++ Program for largest sum contiguous subarray](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-for-largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You forgot to initialize `j` before each loop at `for (j;j<n;j++){`
- You wrongly swapped `i` and `j` at `sum= sum_lst(lst,i,j);`
- `sum` is not initialized, so the result may be wrong if `max_sum` is called multiple times or an array with all negative elements is given.

Fixed code:

```
int sum_lst(int lst[],int debut,int fin){
    int i=debut,sum=0;
    for (i;i<fin;i++){
        sum+=lst[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
int max_sum(int lst[],int n){
    int i=n;
    static int sum;
    int j=0;
    if (n<=0) return 0;
    sum = lst[0]; /* initialize sum */
    for (i;i>0;i--){
        for (j=0;j<n;j++){ /* initialize j */
            if (sum_lst(lst,j,i)>sum){
                sum= sum_lst(lst,j,i); /* don't swap i and j */
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: i don't understand why you said that i swap i and j i though that it was good